# Eclipse - Reportes BIRT - Aggregation

Tags: sql, eclipse, plugin, function, report

Saludos, si alguien trabaja con el plugin de *Reportes para Eclipse BIRT*, tengo una pregunta sobre la funcionalidad de **Aggregation**, sus usos no los tengo muy claros, es decir todo su potencial. Se que se puede usar en una tabla para agregar un campo que funcione como sumador de los demás, esto facilita el tener que hacer formulas especificas. Para refrescar un poco aquí unas imágenes:
[image: Ventana de Aggregation Builder]

Vemos que tiene la opcion de Function: donde existe una gran cantidad de funciones a utilizar, (si tienen alguna documentación de BIRT que hable bien de esta funcionalidad se los agradecería) y con algunos ejemplos.

Al punto, ***¿en esta característica puedo crear para que tome el MontoTotal + IVA y lo agregue en un campo? ¿como lo haría con esta manera, o hay otra manera de hacerlo?***

Es que no tengo muy Claro que va en *Expression y Filter Condition*, y si cambio la *Function* aparecen mas cosas... me intriga que no este aprovechando esta funcionalidad. Si coloco una Expression lo que este seleccionado en Function no le importara? ese campo es como para ayudar a crear o es indispensable?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, conozco que se puede agregar desde la paleta o **Insert - Data** en el campo que quieras, le pones el **nombre**, el **tipo** y ahí la **formula**, con la formula uno puede hacer lo que quiera, pero no se el uso del *Aggregation* creo que es mas especifico para sumas de totales, pero creo que eso mismo lo puedes hacer agregando un **"Data"** en donde quieres el resultado.

Pero mejor espera a que alguien mas confirme y expanda mas.

Recuerda que...

La cantidad de Impuesto es:

**(Monto*ImpuestoPorcentaje) / 100**

Ejemplo:

**200*12/100 = 24**

Entonces el *TotalConImpuesto* es: **200+24 = 224**

*Nota*: fíjate que no puedes aquí usar el comodín de **12/100 = 0.12** **NO** es valido hacer **200*0.12** ya que la formula correcta es **(200*12)/100**

y que si quieres saber el Impuesto teniendo el Monto Total ya con el, (es decir si quieres separarlo) seria:

**MontoConIVA / 1.(ImpuestoPorcentaje)**

Ejemplo:

**224/1.12 = 200** (monto sin impuesto)